# Retrieving list of files in a directory with a full path in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, os.path

I have this code working with local files:

```
path = r'/localhost_path/'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    subpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if subpath.endswith('.txt'):
        print("TXT")
```

I was trying to replace it with SFTP with Paramiko, but it didn't work.
Paramiko doesn't have a `.join` option – how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to retrieve a list of files in a given directory with a full path, you can use this:

```
path = "/remote/path"
for filename in sftp.listdir(path):
    fullpath = path + "/" + filename
    print(fullpath)
```